# Update Android strings from POEditor (Gradle path error)

Tags: android, string, gradle, localization

I want to translate my android application to other languages using [www.poeditor.com](http://www.poeditor.com) tool. I found [project](https://github.com/lukin0110/poeditor-gradle) in git which lets to get translations from POEditor and put them directly to required folders.

My build.gradle file look

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'be.lukin.poeditor:gradle:0.3.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'poeditor'
poeditor {
    apikey 'api_key'
    projectId 'project_id'
    type 'android_strings'
    terms 'App/src/main/res/values/strings.xml'

    trans 'en', 'App/src/pro/res/values-en'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And I am trying to execute this command
`gradle poeditorInit` , but it leads to the error:

```
C:\Users\PC\.gradle\daemon\2.7\App\src\main\res\values\strings.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I think it is some kind of problem with gradle path. I tried to execute commands with `gradle` and `gradlew` - results were the same. Tried to change project path with `gradle -p "Path_to_project"` - nothing happens.

Maybe someone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try 
`gradlew poeditorInit -g /`  or
`gradlew poeditorPull -g /`
The second one worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the plugin. I did develop & test it on a Mac but not on Windows. When the plugin is handling the translation files it constructs a full path by concatenating the path of the translation file with the root path of your project (where gradlew is located).

Somehow this fails on Windows. Can your report an issue on: https://github.com/lukin0110/poeditor-gradle/issues

Comment: I have already raised an issue for this. Please check. https://github.com/lukin0110/poeditor-gradle/issues/16